# how can i call a intent from spinners onitemSelected method

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a spinner control in my android app, I want the user to select an option from the spinner. Once the option is selected the user can be redirected to another intent. My problem is how do i call intent from onitemselcted method of the spinner??.

Or i am doing wring there is other way in which i can do this. I need the user to set the option from the dropdown first before proceeding to the next page.

> If i put startactivity(intent) in my onitemselected method i get this
>   error The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type
>   MyOnItemSelectedListener (Myonitemselectedlistner is my class which
>   implements OnItemSelectedListener)

this is my onitemslectedlistner code

```
    class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

        Context ctx = view.getContext();

        SharedPreferences myPrefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences("hello", android.content.Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE );

        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();     
        prefsEditor.putString("city", parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());    
        prefsEditor.commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(ctx, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);


    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {

        //do nithong
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u post your Spinner OnItemSelcted method's Code.

Comment: Instead of     Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(ctx, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
 change to startActivity(new Intent(Classnmae.this,Main.class))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing something like:

```
YourParentClassName.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Here's the fully tested implementation... THIS WORKS:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 1){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
                MyActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // To do ...
        }

    });
```

Comment: I just updated my answer with a FULLY TESTED solution that works.  Don't have your activity implement OnItemSelectedListener.  You don't need to.  Obviously, adjust the names of the classes to match yours.  If this does not work for you, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your onitemselected method is inside a private class that implements OnItemSelectedListener, which doesn't define startActivity.  The startActivity method is part of Activity.

You should create a method in the parent activity, and call startActivity from there.  You can make a call from your private class into your parent activity.

Comment: if i do like this it ask me to make that method static if i make the method define as part of activity static i can call start activity its says Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method

Answer (score 0):

make your activity implements this interface

```
    public class MyApp implements OnItemSelectedListener{

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

        Context ctx = view.getContext();

        SharedPreferences myPrefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences("hello", android.content.Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE );

        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();     
        prefsEditor.putString("city", parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());    
        prefsEditor.commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(ctx, MainActivity.class);
        MyApp.this.startActivity(intent);


    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {

        //do nithong
    }



}
```